# Can any one explain me the below phrase that contains 'too sees' what does that mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, headlinese

> 10th day of winter session **too sees** ruckus over demonetisation move.
>   <sub>From: [The Hindu](http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/10th-day-of-winter-session-too-sees-ruckus-over-demonetisation-move/article16729201.ece?homepage=true), National News, November 30th</sub>

What does this mean "too sees"? I didn't understand this phrase.

Comment: No @AbsoluteBeginner there is no comma after to it's a headline from the Hindu http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/10th-day-of-winter-session-too-sees-ruckus-over-demonetisation-move/article16729201.ece?homepage=true

Comment: I mean that "too" refers to the "10th day", not to "sees". Also the 10th day...sees...

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Thank you for your clarification and can you tell me in which context we have to use the word "over".I am very confused to use the word over

Comment: It means that there is ruckus "connected to/because of" demonatization. Compare "quarrel over something". ,

Comment: @RAJARAM I think you would understand the sentence if you read this *... too ...* as "..., like other days, ...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is clearer to replace "too" with

> also

since they are equivalent

> 10th day of winter session **also sees** ruckus over demonetisation move.